# Read an html attribute value from a Thymeleaf fragment

Tags: java, templates, thymeleaf

i'm using thymeleaf as the template engine on a Java - Spring web application which is already a completed website, what i'm working now is to introduce some *<meta>* tags in the header to optimize the interaction with social network platforms.

My goal is to accomplish this modifying as little as possible of the templates code, and to have some flexibility on which values goes into the tags content.

Right now the templates are structured as follows:

**Layout.html**  which contains a couple fragments for head and body.

```html
<head th:fragment="common_head(title, links, scripts)" th:assert="${!#strings.isEmpty(title)}">
...
</head>

<body th:fragment="common_body(content, body_end)">
...
</body>
```

And the templates for the actual pages are something like this.

```html
<head th:replace="common/layout :: common_head(~{:: head/title}, ~{}, ~{:: head/script})">
    <title>My page title</title>
    <script>
        console.log('some page specific JS code');
    </script>
    ...
</head>
<body th:replace="common/layout :: common_body(~{ :: body/content }, ~{ :: body/bottom })">
    <div class="wrapper" th:fragment="content">
        some content here
    </div>
    <th:block th:fragment="bottom">
        more content here
    </div>
</body>
```

I know i can just add another parameter to **common_head** fragment and pass the <meta> tags to it the same way i'm doing with title, scripts, etc. but i was thinking on another approach which will lead to less repetition of code to inject the values into the header.

In the layout *common_head* fragment i have this:

```html
<meta property="og:title"       th:with="og_value = ~{this :: %og_title/text()}"       th:content="${og_value ne null ? og_value : 'Lorem ipsum'}">
<meta property="og:description" th:with="og_value = ~{this :: %og_description/text()}" th:content="${og_value ne null ? og_value : 'Lorem ipsum'}">
<meta property="og:image"       th:with="og_value = ~{this :: %og_image}"              th:content="${og_value ne null ? og_value : 'path-to-default-img'}">
```

The idea is to use fragment selectors to pick the right content to inject from the page template, this way in a page i can just mark a tag (maybe a div, a paragraph, something relevant for that template) with *th:ref="og_description"* and it's value will become the *content* of the <meta> tag in the head.

This works really well for *og_title* and *og_description* tags, but the problem arises with the *og:image* meta tag, in which i need to inject the value of the **src** attribute of an <img> tag marked with *th:ref="og_image"*.

I couldn't find any way to read an attributes value from the fragment, **is there a way to do this?**.

I can see that the selected fragment is actually an instance of [*org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Fragment*](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.1.RELEASE/index.html?org/thymeleaf/standard/expression/Fragment.html) but i don't see any method i can use to access the html attributes in it.

If this is not technically possible, is there a better approach to this use case?